# Using the ExchangeOnlineManagement Powershell module inside Powershell Azure Functions

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, office365

I've been trying to use the ExchangeOnlineManagement module inside a Powershell Azure Function. This is the whole script so far:

```
using namespace System.Net
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

$userPrincipalName = $Request.Body.userPrincipalName
$organization = $Request.Body.organization
$groupNames = $Request.Body.groupNames

try {
    Connect-ExchangeOnline -AppId 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 `
        -Organization $organization `
        -CertificateThumbprint $certThumbPrint `
        -ErrorAction Stop `
        -ShowBanner:$false `
        -ShowProgress:$false `
        -CommandName Add-DistributionGroupMember
    
    foreach ($group in $groupNames) {
        try {
            Write-Information "Adding $($userPrincipalName) to the group $($group)"
            Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$($group)" `
                -Member "$($userPrincipalName)" `
                -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck
        }
        catch {
            Write-Error $_
        }
    }

    $successMessage = "$($userPrincipalName) has been added to the distribution groups."
    Write-Information $successMessage
    Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
            StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
            Body       = @{
                Success = $true
                Message = $successMessage
            }
        })
}
catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
    Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
            StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
            Body       = @{
                Success = $false
                Message = $_.Exception.Message
            }
        }) 
}
finally {
    Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -Confirm:$false
}
```

Everything works nice the first time I execute it, but I get this error if I try to run it more than once:

> [Error] ERROR: One or more errors occurred. (An HttpListenerException occurred while >listening on http://localhost:50397/ for the system browser to complete the login. Possible >cause and mitigation: the app is unable to listen on the specified URL; run 'netsh http add >iplisten 127.0.0.1' from the Admin command prompt.)Exception             :Type    : >Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorExceptionMessage

This problem doesn't happen when I debug the function locally, it only happens when it is hosted on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I was passing the Certificate Thumbprint using the variable `$certThumbPrint` that was defined on the file *profile.ps1*. It turns out that information is lost after the function is executed once. I moved the thumbprint to the application settings, retrieved it from the script using `$env:CERT_THUMBPRINT` and that fixed the problem.